# How do I make the taskbar show my progress bar in PyQt4?

Tags: python, pyqt, progress-bar, taskbar

I'm using PyQt4 to display a progress bar in my application, but I want it to also be seen on the taskbar, just like many programs such as winRAR and google chrome do. Is there a way to make that happen?

Comment: Related: [How to show progress in windows 7 taskbar (using Qt)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4349502/how-to-show-progress-in-windows-7-taskbar-using-qt) and [Qt: what is the current status of Windows 7 Taskbar Extensions support?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1518620/qt-what-is-the-current-status-of-windows-7-taskbar-extensions-support). In particular, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1518620/qt-what-is-the-current-status-of-windows-7-taskbar-extensions-support/3694401#3694401).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you'll want to setup your QProgressBar (not  QProgressBarDialog) and insert into QStatusBar (or QMainWindow.statusBar()) with the [insertWidget()](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qstatusbar.html#insertWidget), then use removeWidget to remove it when you're done with it.

Answer (score 2):

in PyQT5 you must use addWidget()

```
class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, mainwindow_test.Ui_MainWindow):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.statusbar.addWidget(self.progressBar)
```