# How do I add a ProgressBar to the StatusBar using PySide?

Tags: python, progress-bar, pyside, statusbar

I'm wanting to add a progress bar into my application's status bar.  I've found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6892039/447015), however using `insertWidget()` doesn't appear to be working.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of using the `insertWidget()` method use instead [`addPermanentWidget()`](https://deptinfo-ensip.univ-poitiers.fr/ENS/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QStatusBar.html?highlight=insertwidget#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QStatusBar.addPermanentWidget).

Here's an example:

```
class SampleBar(gui.QMainWindow):
    """Main Application"""


    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        print('Starting the main Application')
        super(SampleBar, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        # Pre Params:
        self.setMinimumSize(800, 600)

        # File Menus & Status Bar:
        self.statusBar().showMessage('Ready')
        self.progressBar = gui.QProgressBar()


        self.statusBar().addPermanentWidget(self.progressBar)

        # This is simply to show the bar
        self.progressBar.setGeometry(30, 40, 200, 25)
        self.progressBar.setValue(50)

def main():
    app = gui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = SampleBar()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This should produce something like this:

[image: Progress Bar]